# "IMCE Uploader" module is preventing some file types from being uploaded within IMCE

Tags: files

I have downloaded and enabled the "IMCE Uploader" module at https://drupal.org/project/imce_uploader

This module allows you to within IMCE to upload multiple files at one time and is working better than the "IMCE plupload" module which I have found has corrupted some files after uploading.

I have configured the Media browser settings at /admin/config/media/browser to include a lot of file types (including jsonp, docx and xlsx) and without having the "IMCE Uploader" module enabled they all display when trying to do an upload within IMCE.

After enabling the "IMCE Uploader" and "IMCE Uploader - Plupload" modules I have noticed that some file types like jsonp, docx and xlsx are not allowed anymore when trying to do an upload within IMCE.

Is there any way that I can allow these additional file types to be uploaded within IMCE when using the "IMCE Uploader" and "IMCE Uploader - Plupload" modules?

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that perhaps your allowed file types has changed in your IMCE profile, or IMCE Uploader has created a new profile for you and is using it by default. Check admin/config/media/imce/ and make sure the profile you are using allows those file types.